# Create Jenkins Build Job to Package only selected classes to .war file

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm currently setting up a Jenkins build job for my Maven project, and I need some guidance on how to configure it to package only specific classes. Here's the scenario:

I have a large Maven project with several modules, and I want to create a Jenkins build job that builds the project and packages only a subset of classes from one of the modules. These selected classes contain critical functionality that needs to be deployed separately from the rest of the project.

I added the following as build job:

```
clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.war.include=WEB-INF/classes/ch/irix/asco/business/bid/boundary/BidStackCreationResource.class,WEB-INF/classes/ch/irix/asco/business/bid/boundary/BidStackCreationResourceImpl.class,WEB-INF/classes/ch/irix/asco/business/biddingparameter/entity/BiddingParameterEntity.class,WEB-INF/classes/ch/irix/asco/business/bid/helper/InterpolationPoint.class,WEB-INF/classes/ch/irix/asco/business/bid/helper/InterpolationFunction.class,WEB-INF/classes/ch/irix/asco/business/resource/boundary/ResourceProductTimeSeriesBTO.class,WEB-INF/classes/ch/irix/asco/business/bid/entity/BidTsEntity.class,WEB-INF/classes/ch/irix/asco/business/bid/entity/BidTsEntityParameterEntity.class,WEB-INF/classes/ch/irix/asco/business/bid/control/BidCreationService.class,WEB-INF/classes/ch/irix/asco/business/bid/entity/BidEntity.class
```

Which should include all necessary classes but if i inspect the created .war file, all classes are present in the WEB-INF folder.

Any suggestions how to achieve that?

Comment: I don't think this will work passing options on the command line.  You will need to modify the pom.xml and configure the war plugin to only include the classes you want.  You may need to create a few different executions if you want one war file with all the classes and another with just select classes.

Comment: So is it possible to use a different pom.xml in this specific build job? I'm not that fit in this subject so excuse my newbie questions.

Comment: Why would you like to package ony selected classes into a war file? Why not all in that war module... A subset of a module sounds like your module is wrong ? If you have to create them separately it would make more sense to create a common module and for example two separate modules which contain one set and the other module another set... makes it much more easier... instead of command line options...

Comment: I would tend to agree with @khmarbaise but I have a feeling you don't have much control over the application code (application devs) and how it is structured?  To answer your previous question, you wouldn't want to add another pom.xml you would want to make a modification to the existing pom.xml to add a new package execution.  If you decide you want to go that route, I will give some guidance in the form of an answer?

Comment: Strongly consider reworking your sources into multiple modules so a maven module corresponds exactly to a jar. This will give you the least surprises and technical debt.

Comment: Our Java server, deployed in production, offers various functionalities. The customer now requires a specific functionality accessible as a service via REST calls, without a separate deployment of the whole application. This separate deployment should be containerized in a later step. But for now i only want this specific functionality build. 
So if i get this right from the comments, you would suggest to create a module in this project where only the specified functionality is in. And then two build jobs, one that builds the whole application and one that builds this module?